# More elegant way of doing this in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
@countries = Country.find( :all, :order => 'name' )

@countries_with_tips = []

@countries.each do |country|
  if country.tips.any?
    @countries_with_tips.push( country )
  end
end
```

I am getting each country that has at least one tip.  A country has_many tips and a tip belongs_to a country

It works.  But for Ruby it seems a little unelegant.  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: If you find yourself doing this kind of queries very often, consider using counter caching (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, section 4.1.2.4). You'll be able to do your query this way: `Country.where('tips_count > 0')`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ad that to the list of "stuff to refactor"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@countries_with_tips = Country.joins(:tips).order(:name).uniq
```

Comment: @jdoe Yes, you are right.  Uniq is needed as A country can have multiple tips.  A really elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@countries_with_tips = @countries.select{|country| country.tips.present? }
```